# AWS Lambda caching old code using eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have noticed that from time to time (about twice a day) AWS does not update my Java code and returns previous output from older functions. After a couple of hours it works, and all updates are live and functioning as expected..as though it is not clearing cache.
I am using Eclipse to push my latest code to my Lambda function in AWS.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could it be your eclipse itself? Sometimes these IDE mess up things while packaging stuff.